# How to exclude parts of route based on street features?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap

I have a task. I have a route (coming from whatever, I am using Google Maps for now, but I can switch to OSM), and I want to exclude some parts of this route based on street features (like I don't need highways). I need to do it automatically on node.js server. Can you suggest any tools I can use on server side to solve this problem?
EDIT: I added some info, that I need to do it not manually, but automatically on node.js-based server.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the data of OSM in shapefile directly from [geofabrik.de](http://download.geofabrik.de/) and adjust the data as you like using select by attribute to select the desired attribute information that you need and exclude other information that you don't need from the original data. Also, you can refer to [this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html) on how to search and download OSM from inside QGIS and do the necessary adjustments based on your criteria.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention it initially, but I need to do it automatically on my own server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this [tool from Mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/route-annotator) can do what I need. I only need to look at how it works and do it with database, not in memory.